# Ubuntu terminal - go to mouse cursor position

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I often run my research experiments through my terminal. The command is a very long one, and often I find the need to change a parameter to the call. The problem is that the call line is long, and the parameter is for example in the middle of the line. To replace the parameter I must keep holding the left arrow/right arrow until I reach the point where the parameter is, then delete and rewrite the characters.

Is there a way to navigate the terminal command line using the mouse cursor position? Clicking in the middle of the line doesn't do anything, of course.

Example:

> Suppose I have, in the terminal:
>
> ~> runThisProgram(a,b,c,d,......,v,w,x,y,z).
>
> Now I want to run it but with X instead of the parameter c. I have to go to the end of that line, keep pressing the left arrow until I reach the c, and then delete and write X. (or, symmetrically, go to the beginning of the line, keep pressing the right arrow until I reach the c and then delete and write X). Is there a command to just point at the 'c' position using my cursor and go there?

Comment: It depends on the application whether it uses xterm mouse-mode (bash doesn't have that feature).

Comment: It is GNOME Terminal v 3.18.3, if that helps

Comment: See https://github.com/stephane-chazelas/misc-scripts/blob/master/mouse.zsh for zsh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move word at a time in shell: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> moves cursor one word backward, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> moves one word forward. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> deletes word after cursor. More hotkey combinations for `bash` are explained in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bindable-Readline-Commands).

Comment: not an answer for "Is there a way to navigate the terminal command line using the mouse cursor position?" I don't get why linux and ubuntu in particular is so unfrendly to users. even windows console can navigate through text with mouse clicks

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do what you want.

## Interactive mode

Modern (& most popular) shells, like bash and zsh use GNU readline as input library. See [man 3 readline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/readline), section **Editing Commands**. There are two modes : emacs and vi.

### Emacs style

`set -o emacs`

@sebasth's answer covers this part.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (or <kbd>UP</kbd>): Last command

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>: Word backward

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>: Word forward

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>: Delete next word

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd>: Delete previous word

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>: Beginning of the line

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>: End of the line

### Vi style

`set -o vi`

Press <kbd>I</kbd> to go in insertion mode and <kbd>ESC</kbd> to go in command mode. Go in command mode and then:

<kbd>K</kbd>: Last command

<kbd>B</kbd>: Word backward

<kbd>W</kbd>: Word forward

<kbd>DW</kbd>: Delete next word

<kbd>DB</kbd>: Delete previous word

<kbd>0</kbd>: Beginning of the line

<kbd>$</kbd>: End of the line

## Using an external editor

`fc` will paste your last command (you can also specify another command in your history) in your favorite editor (see $EDITOR variable). The command will be run when exiting the editor.

When the command line start getting longer and longer you might want to use a real editor instead of shell's readline. As a bonus, you can save it as a script file on your disk.

## Modify just 1 parameter

Using `^before^after` allows to replace string `before` by `after`.

For instance:

```
abitbol@localhost $ echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7

abitbol@localhost $ ^3^42
echo 1 2 42 4 5 6 7 
1 2 42 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: This is certainly useful information for someone wanting to edit long lines in the terminal, but it does not seem to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using `bash` so you could use a `readline` function that sets the variable `READLINE_POINT`, which is the position of the text cursor, to the desired column. A cheap way to find the column would be to select (with the mouse) all the text from the start of the line to the desired position, and use `xsel` to read this selection.

For example, to try it out, bind character `!` to a function `gotocolumn`:

```
$ bind '-x "!":gotocolumn' 
$ gotocolumn(){ local x=$(xsel);READLINE_POINT=${#x}; }
```

Recall a long line, select a few characters from the front, type `!` and the cursor is moved.

---

I just noticed that moving the text cursor to be at the mouse position is actually built-in to **xterm** with the `readline-button` function, and just needs a suitable binding. For example, run

```bsh
xterm -xrm 'XTerm.VT100.translations:  #override\
 Mod4 <Btn1Down>: readline-button()\n'
```

then when you click the mouse left button with the Meta (or Super) key over a character in an input line, xterm generates left or right keys until the cursor lines up.

Similarly, **urxvt** has a built-in perl extension (see `man urxvt-readline`), enabled by default, with a binding of Shift and left button.

Comment: This seems to be the only answer here that actually attempts to answer the question. However, it is not clear to me after reading this answer how I would “use a `readline` function that sets the variable `READLINE_POINT`”. Is the example a script that I would source on login?

Comment: The example 2 lines can be typed in to your bash shell to try it out. You can put the same 2 lines (without the `$ `) into your `~/.bashrc` which is sourced by any interactive bash. It should then be available in any terminal.

Comment: @RandyCragun Just noticed there is a built-in solution for xterm and urxvt, details in updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a simple shell script and use shell variables for the parameters that you'd like to tweak:

```
#!/bin/sh

param_c=340

./myprogram 1 2 "$param_c" \
            4 5 6 7
```

Comment: Most of the time the program I want to call would change. Sometimes the parameter I want to change changes. This is not relevant, I'm sorry. It is not logical to start creating scripts for every single kind of program I want to call and parameter I want to change.

Comment: @TheNotMe I thought you were referring to a single specific program when you wrote "The command is a very long one, and often I find the need to change a parameter to the call".

Comment: Sorry, my bad for not making it clearer. I upped your answer since it can be useful in that case.